# Adding a background-image to Google Maps

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to achieve this maps overlay effect with a live Google map or does it have to be a static image?

http://penandthink.com/foldit/

Thanks
Greg

**Update**

Fiddle published [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/4/) based on another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/3/) from @SinistraD

Comment: Yeah its possible. Show us some code to get started.

Comment: I'm the guy behind the FoldIt demo. I couldn't figure out an easy way to make the map interactive so I'm glad to find people tinkering with it here!

Those Fiddle examples were linking directly to a PNG from a page that I htaccess blocked, so if anyone would like to update them, here's an more conveniently hosted version of the image: http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/6726/framev.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't do it with a live Google map. You would just overlay the PNG over the live map instead of a static map. The problem however, is that you lose the interactivity of the live Google map as the PNG overlay blocks the mouse events (e.g. dragging) from reaching the live map. There are JavaScript ways around this, however not necessarily easy nor elegant.

Comment: Hmm, as @SinistraD points out, this doesn't seem _that_ easy. I have made edits to his [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/3/) to use the Google API directly (instead of embedding an iframe) but it still doesn't work. Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/4/)

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion this is a nice question.

It SHOULD be possible but unfortunetly I can't do it. I tried without success. There are a few problems.

Let's start with the image overlaying.
The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="map">
    <img id="map-paper" src="http://penandthink.com/foldit/frame.png"/>
    <iframe ... google maps code... ></iframe>
</div>​
```

And the CSS something like this:

```
#map {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

#map iframe {
    margin: 10px;
}

#map-paper {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://penandthink.com/foldit/frame.png');
}
```

This almost works, but not completely, there are parts that are not covered completely for some reason I couldn't find.

The second problem is the loss of behavior. The problem with this is, that you have to simulate the click below the image. So, something like this jQuery code should work, but it doesn't:

```
$('#map').click(function(e) {
    $(this).children('iframe').click(e);
});​
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/3/)'s a fiddle for all this.

I know this isn't really an answer (well, maybe a proof that it's not so simple to do it), rather some starting point for others trying to tweak with this.

Comment: I tried to use to Google API directly without luck. I modified your Fiddle but now the issue is that the PNG doesn't overlay the map. I have tried changing the z-indexes around but haven't had any luck. My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/4/)

Comment: In your fiddle the HTML is removed. You shouldn't init the map on #map div directly, you should do it on a child of it instead. Like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/5/). The overlying now works (with z-index: -1) but the behavior is still missing

Comment: Interesting, I'm stumped. I did find that you can get Google Maps to listen to DOM events with  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'click', function(event){}) [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) but I can't simulate the click back into Maps. E.g., google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click'); doesn't fire the appropriate event in Google Maps. Fiddle [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc6P/6/)

Comment: There's no way that could work. How would google know the coordinates of the click? The browser wont tell, because you didn't actually click on it. Somehow you need to pass the event object the browser gives to your event handler.

Comment: Maybe this Stackoverflow would be help us: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860277/javascript-passing-click-event-to-google-maps-through-a-overlapping-div